# Unable to create layer for Linear Layout in android version 9

Tags: android, exception, google-fabric, android-9.0-pie

In fabric crashlytics logged this exception just in version android 9 and device Galaxy J6+ Galaxy J4+ and HMD Global Nokia 2.1.

```
 MessageQueue.java
 android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce
 Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException
 Unable to create layer for LinearLayout, size 704x4160 max size 8192 color 
 type 4 has context 1
 android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce (MessageQueue.java)
 android.os.Looper.loop + 181 (Looper.java:181)
 android.app.ActivityThread.main + 7097 (ActivityThread.java:7097)
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main + 975 (ZygoteInit.java:975)
```

Comment: What's inside the LinearLayout?

Comment: @sweggersen There is no information on this issue

Comment: https://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=SDK&messageId=372855&startId=zzzzz~&curPage=2&searchType=TITLE&searchText=bug

Comment: https://android--kotlin.blogspot.com/2019/07/android-java-lang-illegalstateexception-unable-to-create-layer-for-linearlayout.html